# Setting multiple if conditions with a jQuery chart plugin called piety

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g49r3c97/3/)

I want to use different color combinations in a small chart plugin called [piety](http://benpickles.github.io/peity/)
The document shows this code to set different colors of a pie chart:

```
$(".bar-colours-1").peity("bar", {
  fill: ["red", "green", "blue"]
});

$(".bar-colours-2").peity("bar", {
  fill: function(value) {
    return value > 0 ? "green" : "red";
  }
});

$(".bar-colours-3").peity("bar", {
  fill: function(_, i, all) {
    var g = parseInt((i / all.length) * 255);
    return "rgb(255, " + g + ", 0)";
  }
});

$(".pie-colours-1").peity("pie", {
  fill: ["cyan", "magenta", "yellow", "black"]
});

$(".pie-colours-2").peity("pie", {
  fill: function(_, i, all) {
    var g = parseInt((i / all.length) * 255);
    return "rgb(255, " + g + ", 0)";
  }
});
```

Would it be possible to use multiple if conditions to render the chart in different color combinations based on the values?

Failed code:

```
$(".score").peity("pie", {
  fill: function(value) {
    if(value > 0){ 
      return value ["#c6d9fd", "#ff9900"];
    }
    else if(value > 200){ 
      return value ["#BFE5E5","#46ECA0"];
    }
    else if(value > 300){
      return value ["#BAAB48","#E7F94A"];
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class='score'>5/150</span>
<span class='score'>220/250</span>
<span class='score'>320/350</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I responded to your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/benpickles/peity/issues/48) thusly:

Hi, I've modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benpickles/0ejq9qdL/

When passing a function to `fill` it's called for each value in the chart and should respond with a single colour for the particular slice/bar.

Get back to me if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arranging your `if` statements in the opposite order, i.e.:

```
if (value > 300) { .. }
else if (value > 200) { .. }
else if (value > 0) { .. }
```

The way you currently have it, any value over 0 will take the first branch of your `if else if else if` and neither of the second two conditions will ever be evaluated.